# logging in a module: No handlers could be found for logger

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to enable logging in a module using a logger configured in an executable.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial),

> A good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level logger, in each module which uses logging, named as follows:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I have followed that, creating a module-level logger in my `foo` module:

**module `foo`:**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("hello world")
```

Again, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging)

> Creating loggers, handlers, and formatters explicitly using Python code that calls the configuration methods listed above.

In my executable I import `foo` and set up the logger, basically a copy-paste of the example int he documentation link above:

**executable:**

```
import logging
from foo import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create console handler and set level to debug
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # add ch to logger
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    logger.info('start')

    f = foo.Foo()
```

I see the log statement from my executable, but my module based logger doesn't work:

> ```
> start
> No handlers could be found for logger "foo.foo"
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I tried using `basicConfig` in my executable, which, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) does the following:

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a `StreamHandler` with a default `Formatter` and adding it to the root logger

**executable:**

```
import logging
from foo import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    ... (same as above) ...

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    logger.info('start')

    f = foo.Foo()
```

And now logging in my module works!

What confuses me is that in my previous example is I *am* creating a `StreamHandler` and adding it to the root logger.

So I guess my question should be:

**What is `basicConfig` doing which explicit calls to the logging configuration api isn't?**

Comment: You are missing the log level when logging: logger.info("hello world")

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign handlers to the `Foo` module logger as well, since they use different logger objects:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(sh)

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("hello world")

==================== RESTART: C:\Python27\tests\test2.py ====================
start
hello world
```

Or you can use `basicConfig` function from the logging module to change the defaults of the root logger and new ones:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    root = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    root.info('start')
    f = Foo()
```

A great resource for logging - [Python Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

---

Update according to the new question:

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger. The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.

In your code, each module has it's own logger object. You need to specify handlers and configurations for each. The basic config basically sets some defaults for you - in case you don't explicity state them. All logger objects are derived from the root logger, so you change the defaults for the root logger and then new loggers derives it.

Comment: How can I configure my logging once, globally, so that all modules use the same logging config? Doesn't seem right that modules decide what level they are going to log at surely, nor what the logging sink will be etc?

Comment: I think this is what you looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

Comment: I was *just* about to say that! I tried using `basicConfig`, and it works! (updating question now) - so I guess the question is, "what is `basicConfig` doing that explicit configuration calls isn't?"

Comment: Ah, so I'm not configuring the root logger in my executable, I'm configuring another one. How do I grab the root logger?

Comment: You call the `getLogger()` method with no args. Basically you should configure the logger in your main module, and then rest of the modules would get the settings from it (if nothing is besides the name of the new loggers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the root logger before you import other modules which will use it as a factory to make their local logger instances.

Change your executable to configure the root logger before getting child loggers

```
import logging
# root logger must be configured before loading child modules which use it
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
# create console handler and set level to debug
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_format = '%(asctime)15s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)s] %(message)s'
console_formatter = logging.Formatter(console_format)
console.setFormatter(console_formatter)
root_logger.addHandler(console)

from foo import foo

# create module specific logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.info('start')

    f = foo.Foo()
```

Then your child module can be like this:

```
import logging

# create module specific logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("hello world")
```